# How to use a slightly modified JMTP library in Java Project?

Tags: java, c++, jmtp

I need to use the following library from GitHub:

https://github.com/reindahl/jmtp

However, there are no build instructions or any instruction how to use it for that matter. I know that the original JMTP libary was downloadable as a jar, which made it easy to use, however with that library, I lack the ability to copy files from a device to the host, hence why I need this library off of GitHub. I am fairly new to working with libraries, and there is not a lot to be found online, so I'm hoping that someone can help me here.

Things I have tried:

Opening the library in IntelliJ and trying to build a JAR, but there is C++ code in the library as well, so that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what can i see from the source code, it has two sections.

The c++ code that produces 32bit and 64bit dll (that are already present, compiled on the repository inside the java section).

The java code, that uses that 32/64 bit dll and that will produce a jar file once compiled.

You should be able to compile and produce the resultant java .jar file, using the java code on the repository. Maybe try to open it with Eclipse, since it has the .project and .classpath files from a Eclipse project, it could make it easier to build, since it has not maven or graddle support.